# How to implement Google Incremental authorization using Supabase

Tags: next.js, google-oauth, gmail-api, supabase, scopes

I have a next.js application that uses supabase and google oauth. I want users to be able to sign into my website with the most basic scopes: profile and email.

When users sign in, they get redirected to the dashboard. However, on my dashboard, I have a button that enables me read access to the user's emails. How can I implement this? How can this button get the extra scope from the user?

Here is my code so far:

On my sign in page, I have this logic:

```js
const handleSignIn = async () => {
  const supabase = supabaseBrowser();
  const { error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
    provider: "google",
    options: {
      redirectTo: "http://localhost:3000/dashboard"
    },
  });
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Now how can I create that button on my dashboard page that gives me the extra gmail scope needed to read user's emails for an additional feature?

How would I tell google oauth that I now need this new scope?

Comment: I believe it's currently not supported on Supabase.

Comment: Ahh man.. any workarounds? How can I still achieve this?

Comment: You could probably perform the initial Google login using Supabase, and then request the additional permissions manually using the `gapi` SDK on your own!  
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth

Comment: Mmm makes sense. I will try it and let you know!